# C# when mysql backup running website Error 524

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-backup

hi I want to backup mysql on c# and I do but if the database is too large web site cannot load. After website is loaded when backup is finished. I think the database stops during backup. Is it possible to take a backup without stopping this?
this is my backu code and i use this [mysqlbackupnet](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mysqlbackupnet)

```
string constring = "server=" + server + ";user=" + user + ";pwd=" + password + ";database=" + database + ";ConvertZeroDatetime=True;";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();
                        mb.ExportToFile(file);
```

Comment: I would generally be very cautious using someone's half-maintained MySQL backup solution if you want to be sure everything actually does get backed up. Instead, I'd just call out to the standard `mysqldump` binary...

Comment: how can i use mysqldump I am new on c# and mysql